# Python Telegram, How to save user input as string

Tags: python, input, telegram, binance

I am making a Telegram trading bot that will create an order after receiving a string from the user. How can I make the bot receive that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the text handler. It passes a dictionary to the function. The dictionary contains a lot of useful information such as the message text, user's name, and id, etc.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):

    print(message)
    your_str = message.text
```

You may also consider the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/) and the examples in particular.